# Move files to their respective folder in linux based on the date of the folder and the date of the file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm fairly new to bash scripting and linux, and I have a folders with just dates such as

```
2012-11-20
2012-11-21
2012-11-22
2012-11-23
```

and I have files with the name data_11202012_randomnumbers_csv.

I would like to create a script that can move every single csv file to it's correct folder by matching the date on the file to the folder.

I've been just typing `mv file path` but i have 100s of files and I'm wondering if theres an easier way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these files and directories in the same directory, side by side? And is the file prefix always `data_`?

Comment: yes they are all in the same directory and yes it's always data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it for you. I will explain with comments

```sh
for file in your_folder/*; do
  # 1. Extract the numbers from the file name
  dir="${file#data_}" # remove data_ prefix
  dir="${dir%%_*}" # remove everything after first _

  # 2. Rearrange the numbers into the desired format
  dir="${dir:2:4}-${dir:0:2}-${dir:6:2}"
  
  # 3. Move the file into the directory
  mv file dir
done
```

[Here](https://devhints.io/bash) you have a very useful bash cheatsheet where you can learn more about it. It illustrates all the variable expansions I've made in my snippet and more.

Comment: ah thank you very much! the cheatsheet helps a lot to understand!